# PHP MD5 implementation

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, md5

I'm currently attempting to code one for part of a college project - binary/hex handling and cryptographic functions are well regarded in the mark scheme, so I thought I'd kill two birds with one stone.

However, the documentation availible on the algorithm itself is thorough but confusing. Is there a prexisting PHP libary/class that I could take a look at, or is there a step by step explanation of the algorithm, and the variables it uses (T and X especially) somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get hold of a copy of Bruce Schneier's [Applied Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099). Although the source code is in C, he does provide an excellent background to the design principles and theory behind the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) has a good write up of the algorithm (along with the valid reasons you should avoid it).

It also contains a full pseudocode example of its implementation.

Comment: Thanks, the Wikipedia write-up seems pretty decent - I just hope it's correct ;)

Comment: Yeah, as much as I use WP, I'd like to believe it's always accurate.  In this case, that implementation looks good to me (but I haven't written an MD5 hasher in a while).

Answer (score 0):

Here's MD5 written in C. I don't know if it'll help, considering it's not PHP, but here it is:
http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=10&ct=rc#zd_oLGoxqmg/md5.c&q=function%20md5.c%20lang:c

Comment: Thanks, but that's the one included in the official RCA. I've tried reading it but to be honest I don't understand much of it.